# Why does mock has not reset in Jest for aws sdk v3 unit testing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am trying to unit test lambda function. I am using [aws-sdk-client-mock](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/mocking-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3-in-unit-tests/) library for mocking.

I am trying to test 5xx status code in my lambda. In order to test it I want to remove mock so that credential error (`CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers`)occurs ( which is obvious ). But since mock of first `describe` is still active I am not able to test it. How do I reset the mock for different describe test cases

**The only way I intend to work if I comment on the first describe block i.e don't use the mock at all.**

```
import { APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { main } from "../../lib/src/lambda/approval-handler";
import { mockClient } from "aws-sdk-client-mock";
import {
    CodePipelineClient
} from "@aws-sdk/client-codepipeline";
import { event, queryStringParameters } from "../utils/lambda-event"


describe("Successful Approve or Deny", () => {. //this works

    const pipelineClientMock = mockClient(CodePipelineClient);

    beforeEach(() => {
        pipelineClientMock.reset();
    });

    it("returns a 301 response with a redirect location if all required query parameters are provided", async () => {

        pipelineClientMock.resolves({})

        const result: APIGatewayProxyResult = await main(event);
        expect(result.statusCode).toEqual(301);
    });

})


describe("When Approval or Deny is not sent successfully", () => { //this fails because mock is still active

    it("returns a 502 error response if any of the required query parameters are missing", async () => {

        const result: APIGatewayProxyResult = await main(event);
        expect(result.statusCode).toEqual(502);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `afterEach` instead

Comment: I tried that didn't work

Comment: https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock/issues/83

Comment: Tried doing this but no luck `const pipelineClientMock = mockClient(CodePipelineClient);
    pipelineClientMock.send.callThrough()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my moving the instance of mockClient inside each describe block.

and then used a `.restore` method which was not documented ( or maybe I missed it)

```
describe("When Approval or Deny is not sent successfully", () => {
    const pipelineClientMock = mockClient(CodePipelineClient);
    beforeEach(() => {
        pipelineClientMock.restore();
    });

    it("returns a 502 error response if any of the required query parameters are missing", async () => {

        const result: APIGatewayProxyResult = await main(event);
        expect(result.statusCode).toEqual(502);
        
    });
});
```

Comment: From the github page >  The restore() removes the mock altogether, restoring the normal behavior of client.send().

Answer (score 0):

I found that using resetHistory() as well as reset was required to get individual tests to run using call data isolated from the rest of the tests.

Using

```
"aws-sdk-client-mock": "^3.0.0",
"aws-sdk-client-mock-jest": "^3.0.0",
```

Before the tests, I've tried reset() and resetHistory() without consistent behaviour. restore() is the only method that works. However, the mock has to be initialised again as from the github page

> The restore() removes the mock altogether, restoring the normal behaviour of client.send()

```
let ddbMock = mockClient(DynamoDBClient)
let sesV2Mock = mockClient(SESv2Client)
describe("Notify Winners", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    ddbMock.restore()
    ddbMock = mockClient(DynamoDBClient)
    sesV2Mock.restore()
    sesV2Mock = mockClient(SESv2Client)
    jest.clearAllMocks()
});
```

The test

```
test('Send approval required notification', async () => {
    ddbMock
        .on(QueryCommand, {ExpressionAttributeValues: {":s": {N: WinPayStatus.new.toString()}}})
        .resolvesOnce({
            Items: [],
            Count: 1
        })
        .on(QueryCommand, {ExpressionAttributeValues: {":s": {N: WinPayStatus.approvalRequired.toString()}}})
        .resolvesOnce({
            Items: [marshall(winnerApprovalRequired)],
            Count: 1,
        })
        .on(GetItemCommand).resolves({Item: marshall(configItem)})

    await main(defaultEvent, defaultContext, () => {
        expect(ddbMock).toHaveReceivedCommandTimes(PutItemCommand, 1);
        expect(sesV2Mock).toHaveReceivedCommandTimes(SendEmailCommand, 1)
    })
})
```

Running the single test with both reset() and resetHistory() returns PutItemCommand being called 1 time.

Running the whole test suite without resetHistory

```
Error: Expected DynamoDBClient to receive "PutItemCommand" 1 times
DynamoDBClient received "PutItemCommand" 3 times
```

Running with resetHistory "PutItemCommand" is recorded as being called 2 times. Asynchronous nature of the tests - i.e. no difference to the result.

I used restore(). Make sure that the mock is created again.